# DependencyProperty Value Inheritance equivalent in UWP

Tags: wpf, uwp, dependency-properties, uwp-xaml

Given a Visual Tree in WPF, it is possible to specify that AttachedProperties are inherited as follows:

```
public static class MyClass 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Foo", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                "AString",
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
}
```

In UWP there is no FrameworkPropertyMetadata and hence you cannot specify FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits.

I had hoped the default behaviour would be to inherit DependencyProperty values but it is not.

Is there any equivalent in UWP to allow inheritance of DependencyProperty **values**?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no equivalent in UWP. Designating a property as inheritable does have some performance considerations. This maybe why it's not available in UWP.

Comment: Booo... OK thanks for info. Hopefully they will add it.

Comment: Just found this UWP limitation in 2017, not possible to create custom Dependency/Attached Properties with inheritance just does not make sense.

Comment: That's not all @MartinSuchan. You also can't create bindings - at all - in a style setter. It beggars belief Microsoft created this framework with so many things missing.